# REST - best practice for returning constants/enums and handling it by JavaScript

Tags: json, api, rest, enums, int

I am developing a web app, which is partially based on ajax calls. The specifics are not important here. One of my entities uses constant ints for status and I need this information in my front end to show it as a string and conditionally show some buttons/info.

```
const STATUS_ORDERED = 1;
const STATUS_WILL_BE_RETURNED = 2;
const STATUS_RECEIVED = 3;
const STATUS_DELAYED = 4;
const STATUS_ARCHIVED = 5;
```

I have several ideas how to include this data in my json response and how to handle it in JavaScript. I am looking for the best way to do this.
My ideas:

- **send status as string** (converted using swich or associative table) - this approach will make it easier to show the status, but including it in logic would involve string comparison
- **send as an int and convert into string on the front end site** - good for logic, string has to be generated somwhere anyway (this seems the most suitable approach for me)
- **send as an int with a translation table** - works nice if only string value is needed, as it makes front more independent, but it does not change anything here, cause I need to check a status on the front end site anyway

Comment: I'm not sure there is a best practice. Like you've indicated, there are pros and cons to each. Personally, in your case I would sent the status as a string. It's easier to understand and makes for more readable code. Using numbers is probably more useful in complex cases where the description is long.

Comment: Description is short, the only thing is I want to show some buttons and info depending on the status, so the front has to be aware of the possible statuses anyway for comparison. Nevertheless, sending numbers feels a bit wrong to me, but so does comparing strings.